# How to embed local HTML file to existing GWT page

Tags: html, gwt, frame

I have a page that is constructed by GWT, when the page get loaded, I will display some required content in it. And then if user click a certain button on the page, I will send request to server side and server will return me a HTML file(a chart generated by jquery plotting tool) stored in local directory, I need to display this HTML file into the existing GWT page's certain widget.

I tried to use Frame in GWT to link to the local HTML file and display it, it get failed, googled and found it's because of browser security setting.Please share your thought, any idea is appreciated.

Comment: You can use `HTML` widget. First fetch the html via RPC call, then `setHTML` on the widget.

Comment: Thanks. I just tried to put the simplest HTML file into GWT HTML widget. <!DOCTYPE html><html><head><title>Page Title</title></head<body><h1>This is a Heading</h1></body></html>.  It's not working, it just displayed the source code of the HTML file in GWT HTML widget

Comment: Strange... I've just made the simplest test and it works for me:   String hmlFileContent = "<!DOCTYPE html><html><head><title>Page Title</title></head<body><h1>This is a Heading</h1></body></html>";
  HTML panel = new HTML(hmlFileContent);
  panel.setPixelSize(500, 500);
  RootPanel.get().add(panel);

Comment: typeof programmer, could you put the code that you are trying in your original question?